# Failed to run Squid on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, squid

I've install Squid by

```
yum install squid
```

and followed the instructions through this [tips](http://www.howtoforge.com/anonymous-proxy-using-squid-3-centos-5.x).

by the time I started Squid and it shows the error that

```
 init_cache_dir /var/spool/squid... /etc/init.d/squid: line 62: 15908 Aborted                 $SQUID -z -F -D 
 /var/log/squid/squid.out 2>&1
```

some of the logs are here...

> 2012/02/09 15:57:37| unrecognised basic auth scheme parameter
>   'childred'
>
> FATAL: auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth: (2) No such
>   file or directory
>
> Squid Cache (Version 2.6.STABLE21): Terminated abnormally.
>
> CPU Usage: 0.004 seconds = 0.000 user + 0.004 sys
>
> Maximum Resident Size: 9824 KB
>
> Page faults with physical i/o: 0

**EDITED** I've searched and the output is

> dpkg-query: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/status'
>   for reading: No such file or directory

Can anybody advise me some solutions ?

Comment: Try `updatedb && locate ncsa_auth`.

Answer (score 1):

2 Problems I think.

1.

The file `/usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth` does not exist according to the error. You can check this by running the following command:

```
file  /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth
```

If you wan't to get Squid running without authentication, have a look at your squid-config and comment lines that have to do with authentication.

Your file wil probably contain the following lines:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Bla bla what you show your users
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic case sensitive off
```

If you want to locate ncsa_auth on your system, use the following command:

```
rpm -qa | grep ncsa_auth
```

or, alternatively:

```
updatedb && locate ncsa_auth
```

You can then change the location in your config file. Make sure the squid-user had appropriate rights to the binary.

2.

You made a typo in your configuration.

`childred` should be `children`. See the config-exerpt above.